# what does it mean to have a void* member of a struct in c?

Tags: c, struct, void-pointers

I don't understand what kind of property the `mystery` member is below:

```
typedef struct _myobject
    {
        long number;
        void *mystery;
    } t_myobject;
```

What kind of member is this `void` member? How much memory does that take up? Where can I get more information about what that accomplishes (for instance, why would one use a `void` member?)

EDIT-- updated title to say void*

Comment: Forget the struct tag, assume it's just `void* mystery;`. Now ask yourself the same questions.

Comment: There is no illegal `void` member, you meant `void*`. `void` is an incomplete type, and the only possible members of incomplete types allowed in `union` and `struct` (as last member) are incomplete array types of complete types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `void*` variable is a "generic" pointer to an address in memory.

The field `mystery` itself consumes `sizeof(void*)` bytes in memory, which is typically either 4 or 8, depending on your system (on the size of your virtual memory address space, to be more accurate). However, it may point to some other object which consumes a different amount of memory.

**A few usage examples:**

```
int var;
char arr[10];
t_myobject obj;

obj.mystery = &var;
obj.mystery = arr;
obj.mystery = malloc(100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `struct` declaration says `void *`, and your question says `void`. A void pointer member is a pointer to any kind of data, which is cast to the correct pointer type according to conditions known at run-time.

A `void` member is an "incomplete type" error.

Answer (score 2):

Variable of type `void *` can hold address of any symbol. Assignment to this variable can be done directly but while dereferencing it needs to be type cast to the actual type. This is required to inform the compiler about how much memory bytes needs to be accessed while dereferencing. Data type is the one which tells the size of a variable.

```
int a = 10;
char b = 'c';
void *c = NULL;
c = &a;
printf("int is %d\n", *((int*)c));
c = &b;
printf("char is %c\n", *(char*)c));
```

In above example `void` pointer variable `c` stores address of `int` variable `a` at first. So while dereferencing `void` pointer `c`, its typecasted to `int *`. This informs the compiler to access 4 byte (size of `int`) to get the value. And then in second `printf` its typecasted to `char *`, this is to inform the compiler to access one byte (size of `char`) to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong question header. The member is 'void *', not 'void'.
A pointer to anything, rather than nothing.